# Mapreduce hadoop error with Gradle

Tags: hadoop, gradle, mapreduce

The **error** which I am getting is as :

> ```
> 16/02/10 11:21:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> 16/02/10 11:21:53 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/outku already exists
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
>     at mr.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
> ```

Please help me How can I resolve this **Error** or what is making this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime hadoop run a MapReduce, it's create a **folder** as an output.

If you want to run the same job, you can specify diferent output folder name, or delete the past one.

Answer (score 0):

`FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/outku`. It means output directory already is exist.

Always specify the output directory name at run time(i.e Hadoop will create the directory automatically for you. You need not to worry about the output directory creation)

you have to delete the existing output directory and try running the M/r Job or change the output directory name